# Уточнение ли это? 3

Tags: пунктуация

Скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая?

В последний год мы развиваем отношения еще с одним зарубежным, на этот раз индийским (,) партнером...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последний год мы развиваем отношения еще с одним зарубежным, **на этот раз индийским**, партнером..

У Розенталя уточняющие определения обособляются, например: Катер шёл, всё время подвигаясь в чёрной, **почти чернильного цвета**, тени.

[§ 22. Уточняющие члены предложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)

Comment: Спасибо большое.